# Changing values on table based on other tables values

Tags: update

I have 2 SQL tables, ROLES and USERLEVELS.
ROLES contain values of usernames and their roles/user types and USERLEVELS contain values of usernames and their user levels.
How do i change user levels of all users that have the same role in this situation?

For example if need to change all the user levels from 9 to 5 if the users role is worker.

EDIT: DBMS is solidDB.

USERLEVELS:

[image: USERLEVELS]

ROLES:

[image: ROLES]